# Setting variables for columns inside bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

My script when run

```
./program < "$1" | awk -F '!' '{print $3 $4, $5, $6, $7}
```

returns the values

```
900 200 30 400 5
51 31 2 3 4
```

How do I set a variable for the colummns for each line
I have attempted

```
LINE=`./program < $1`
for i in $LINE
do
$LINE | awk -f '!' | read a b c d e <<< "$(echo $i | cut -f4 -d:}'
```

but no matter how I do it I can't seem to get values into variables

Comment: `IFS='!' read a b c d e < <(./program < "$1")` ? EDIT: Since there are multiple lines in the output of `./program`, you need a while loop around `read`

Comment: Your question looks like you have `!`-delimited values in the output from `program`, but `cut -f4 -d:` looks like you want to extract the fourth out of a list of colon-delimited fields. Which is correct? Or do you have `!`-delimited fields inside `:`-delimited fields?

Answer (score 3):

You can use process substitution to read these values for each line of output from `awk`:

```
while read -r a b c d e; do
   echo "<$a><$b><$c><$d><$e>"
done < <(./program < "$1" | awk -F '!' '{print $3 $4, $5, $6, $7}')
```

In fact since `awk` is only printing columns delimited by `!` you can even remove awk completely:

```
while IFS='!' read -r a b c d e; do
   echo "<$a><$b><$c><$d><$e>"
done < <(./program < "$1")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $LINE
```

will loop over the *tokens* in LINE. You can modify IFS to make a token equal a line, but then you might as well

```
./program <"$1" |
while IFS='!' read -r a b c d e f g _; do
    echo "<$c$d><$e><$f><$g>"
done
```

Other problems with your attempt:

- `LINE` is not a good variable name.  Use lowercase variable names; uppercase should be regarded as reserved for the shell's special variables.
- Your process substitution attempted to use the loop variable `$i` outside the loop, but that's not possible; it will be undefined.
- `LINE` is not a command name, so its standard output cannot be piped into `awk`.  To pass a string to Awk, do `echo "$LINE" | awk` or, in Bash only, a here string: `<<<"$LINE" awk`
- You have a double redirection to `read`.  It can't read standard input from both the pipe and the here string; the here string will win.  But in this case, because `read` is at the end of a pipeline, it will run in a subshell, and lose its value when the subshell exits.  (You can avoid this in Bash. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 for a discussion.)
- You had mismatched brackets in `$(echo ... | cut ... }`
- You should double-quote the string in `echo "$i"` (although in this isolated case, it might actually have worked).  Generally, unless you specifically require the shell to perform wildcard expansion and token splitting on a variable's value, you should double-quote it.
- No `done` to close the `for ...; do` block.